# How do I split up a row array in GAS?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array which is in range E10:O10 and when I enter the following script:

```
var array1 = ss.getRange('E10:O10').getValues();
Logger.log(array1)
for (var i in array1)
{
panel.add(app.createLabel(array1), 10, 12);  
//Can I do something with array1.length + '' in here to split the values?
}
```

The array comes up with commas between them. Is there any way to split them up and define the pixel width or do you need to use array1.length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays retrieved with getValues are two dimensions even when only one row is extracted. Something like:

```
var array1 = ss.getRange('E10:O10').getValues();
Logger.log(array1)
for (var i = 0; i < array1[0].length; i++ )
{
panel.add(app.createLabel(array1[0][i], 10, 12);  
}
```

Comment: `var array1 = ss.getRange('E10:O10').getValues();
  Logger.log(array1)
  for (var i = 0; i < array1[0].length; i++)
  {
    panel.add(app.createLabel(array1[0][i]), (150 + 45 * i), 12);  
  }` Just edited a bit to make it work - thanks a lot!